# How to declare a React component extending package component in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm looking for a way to declare a React component extending existing component with my own props in Typescript. The source component is ReactD3Tree from `react-d3-tree` npm package v2.0.0. So I have:

```
import ReactD3Tree from "react-d3-tree";
import { TreeProps } from "react-d3-tree/lib/Tree/types";
import { RawNodeDatum } from "react-d3-tree/lib/types/common";

interface MyNode extends RawNodeDatum {
   // some properties
}

interface MyProps extends TreeProps {
   onNodeClick: (targetNode: MyNode, event: Event) => any;
}

let MyTree: React.ComponentClass<MyProps>;


const MyComponentWithOtherOperations = () => {
    ...some more code here enter code here

    return <MyTree data={data} onNodeClick={handleNodeClick} />
}
```

My question is how do I properly override `onNodeClick` prop of `ReactD3Tree` that accepts `targetNode: RawNodeDatum` as a parameter? I want to have `targetNode: MyNode` as a parameter where `MyNode` extends `RaNodeDatum` Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you planning to use `ReactD3Tree`?

Comment: @RameshReddy I want to override `onNodeClick` method which accepts a node as a parameter. I want to have my custom node there.

Comment: TypeScript supports multiple level inheritance. You can extend **ReactD3Tree** which extends React.Component. Is there a problem with this approach ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839146/extending-base-class-methods-with-multiple-levels-of-inheritance-typescript

Comment: @AkhmediyarSailaubekov I got what you're trying to do. See - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rd3t-v2-custom-event-handlers-5pwxw?file=/src/App.js), prop for [custom nodes](https://bkrem.github.io/react-d3-tree/docs/interfaces/_tree_types_.treeprops.html#rendercustomnodeelement).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to pass an extra parameter to your NodeClick event handler. What you are looking for is a curried function.

```
const nodeClickHandler = customprop => nodeValue => {
     console.log(customprop, nodeValue); 
};

const MyComponentWithOtherOperations = () => {
    ...some more code here enter code here

    return <MyTree data={data} onNodeClick={nodeClickHandler("your custom data")} /> }
```